# What does it mean to call angular.extend() on two functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read through the code here:

http://jsbin.com/wecisumumu/1/edit?html,js,output

However, this calls

```
angular.extend(wrap, $delegate);
```

where `wrap` and `$delegate` are two functions. The [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) say that extend is called on two objects. What does it mean to call it on two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript functions are also objects:

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log('hello!')
}

foo.test = 'hi!'

foo() // hello!
console.log(foo.test) // hi!
```

Answer (score 0):

It means this function put those two objects together. For example:`var a angular.extend({a: 1}, {b: 2})`
result: {a: 1, b : 2}

params: first param is distination object, second and others are source. You can point any amount of object `angular.extend(dist, sour1, sour2)`

return referense on a distination object

Comment: I believe OP already knows the purpose of extend(); they are asking what is happening when you pass functions as parameters instead of plain objects.

Comment: function is object, isn't it? It's obviously.

Comment: I don't think it's that obvious, depending on the programming background you have ;)

Comment: It's true. Anyway i hope my answer once will help someone)